# How to access geoJson coordinates array in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, geojson

I have the following GeoJSON output shortened for read reasons:

```
geoDefinition:
    features: Array(1)
    0:
    geometry:
        coordinates: Array(1)
            0: Array(5)
                0: (2) [5.39014, 43.279295]
                1: (2) [5.393069, 43.279249]
                2: (2) [5.391814, 43.278421]
                3: (2) [5.390709, 43.278749]
                4: (2) [5.39014, 43.279295]
                length: 5
```

My goal is to get the coordinates array and store it in another more general Array.
In the code, I wrote:

```
   this.locations.forEach(element => {
      this.polygons = element.geoDefinition.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
```

Whilst feature[0] is defined,

[image]

geometry remains *undefined*. I cannot access to geometry->type / coordinates.

coordinates is an Array of Arrays:

[image]

Could someone show me what I did wrong please?

Best Regards,

Comment: are you sure your features is an array, and not an object? try features["0"].geometry.coordinates

Comment: You are assigning to the same var "polygons" inside forEach. Are you sure this is ok?

Comment: Can you put your  json data structure so that we can see the actual object with properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Here is a working proof:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-puskp8

```
const locations = [
  {
    geoDefinition:
    {
      features:
        [{
          geometry:
          {
            coordinates: [

              [5.39014, 43.279295],
              [5.39014, 43.279295],
              [5.39014, 43.279295],
              [5.39014, 43.279295],


            ]
          }
        }]
    }
  }
]


const newArr = []
locations.forEach(obj => {
  newArr.push(...obj.geoDefinition.features[0].geometry.coordinates)

})

console.log('copied array is', newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that features is an object and not an array in the definition.

That would mean that, to access the element '0' instead of feature[0], you should use `feature['0']`.

Comment: feature['0'] fixes my problem. Thank you.